# Adding Menubar to Gridpane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, menubar, gridpane

How do I add a `MenuBar` to a stage? I have tried including it in my `GridPane` (which I have added all my other elements to) but it never looks as if it is attached to the top of the window.

[image: Example of what it looks like.]

Is there anyway to solve this?

I used this code to place it in the layout.

```
 layout.add(menuBar,0,1,10,1);
```

Where `layout` is the `GridPane`, and `menuBar` is the `MenuBar` with the menu things added.

Comment: Don't add a `MenuBar` to a `GridPane`.

Comment: Wrap the `GridPane` and the `MenuBar` in a different layout, e.g. `BorderPane`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this in code, try using a better node as the `root`. When I have a `MenuBar`, I love to use `VBox`. You can add your `GridPane` after the `MenuBar`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication249 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Menu miFile = new Menu("File");
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().add(miFile);

        VBox root = new VBox(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]