# JavaFx GUI(without scnenbuilder or other drag drop method) with programming

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I am working on a small project using javaFX first time. And I want to make a specific interface which I have a picture linking down. Everyone making GUi with scenebuilder but I have to make it with programming. I have no idea about width and height of listView in GridPane and set all things in it. Can anyone help me with pre-built methods or other methods So can I achieve what looking for
[image]

```
package view;
import java.awt.Button;

import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class CreateSelectModulesPane extends GridPane {

    ListView<String> listview1;
    ListView<String> listview2;
    
    public CreateSelectModulesPane() {
        
        //styling
        this.setVgap(15);
        this.setHgap(20);
        
        this.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        ColumnConstraints column0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column0.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);

        this.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column0);
            
        listview1 = new ListView<>();
        listview1.getItems().addAll("Ebad","Jam");
        this.add(listview1, 0, 1,1,1);

        
    }

    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm (Note that the relevant part is the column under the heading **JavaFX**)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045233/adding-menubar-to-gridpane